# How to fill the Entry Widget to the End of LabelFrame?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

[image]

How to fill the Entry Widget to the Last Automatically Based on the LabelFrame's Width

Comment: Please do not use images of code. Instead put the code in the question. You have conflicting code to what you want.

Comment: Ok, Next i will do that from next time

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a combination of `columnconfigure()` and `sticky='ew'`. I see you are setting height and width of the frame and forcing it by disable grid propagation however I am not 100% sure you need to do that.

Look at the below examples.

Example without `grid_propagate(0)`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('250x200')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Used to allow column 0 in root to expand

some_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Hello')
some_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
some_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Used to allow column 1 in some_frame to expand

entry = tk.Entry(some_frame)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')

root.mainloop()
```

Example with `grid_propagate(0)`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

some_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Hello', width=250, height=200)
some_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
some_frame.grid_propagate(0)  # Not sure why you are doing this You can have the frame expand with the window as well
some_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)  # Used to allow column 1 in some_frame to expand
entry = tk.Entry(some_frame)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')

root.mainloop()
```